# Spark cloud storage response size is larger than the actual files size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a simple spark job that reads parquet files filter, projects, and writes the result to parquet.

Inspecting the scan phase, I noticed that spark is the size of the cloud storage is actually larger than the actual file size.

[image]

Also, the task seems to spend most of their time scanning the file while the network usage is still low. Is there a way to control reader threads?

Comment: Interesting, where do those metrics come from? That does not look like the vanilla Spark UI, but something on top of that.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention, this is run on databricks but with standard spark runtime.